# Flutter update variable from Firebase auth or sharedpreference

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm almost lost I've been working on this for days, I have a Text() widget and passed a variable in it which holds a username from Firebase auth. the issue is I want to check if the user is logged in or not. I could accomplish the username from Firebase if the user logged in but it crashes when not logged in i have tried with shared preference and Firebase current user but it's still not working.
what I have tried:

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String username = 'user name';
  String userEmail = 'email address';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUserName().then((value) {
      username = value;
    });
    getLanguage();
  }

  String language;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  Map data;

  String news;
  String signIn;
  List<Tab> tabs;
  ListView sideBarTabs;

  Future<String> getCurrentUserName() {
    return new Future<String>.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 10000),() async {
      //Do a long running task. E.g. Network Call.
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      //assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

      username = currentUser.displayName;
      return username;
    });
  }

  Future getLanguage() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int lang = prefs.getInt('Language');

    setState(() {
      if (lang != 1) {
        language = 'ku';
        news = 'هه‌وا';
        signIn = 'بچۆ ژووره‌وه‌';
        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      } else{
        language = 'ar';
        news = 'أخبار';
        signIn = 'تسجيل الدخول';
        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> _SignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', user.displayName);
    prefs.setString('useremail', user.email);
    //prefs.setString('IdToken', await user.getIdToken());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 9,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: tabs,
      ),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        "App Name",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
    child: sideBarTabs,
    ),
```

And with sharedpreference:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String username = 'user name';
  String userEmail = 'email address';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUserName().then((value) {
      username = value;
    });
    getLanguage();
  }

  String language;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  Map data;

  String news;
  String signIn;
  List<Tab> tabs;
  ListView sideBarTabs;

  Future<String> getCurrentUserName() {
    return new Future<String>(() async{
      //Do a long running task. E.g. Network Call.
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      username = prefs.getString('username');
      return username;
    });
  }

  Future getLanguage() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int lang = prefs.getInt('Language');

    setState(() {
      if (lang != 1) {
        language = 'ku';

        news = 'هه‌وا';
        signIn = 'بچۆ ژووره‌وه‌';

        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      } else{
        language = 'ar';
        news = 'أخبار';
        signIn = 'تسجيل الدخول';
        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> _SignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', user.displayName);
    prefs.setString('useremail', user.email);
    //prefs.setString('IdToken', await user.getIdToken());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 9,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: tabs,
      ),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        "App Name",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
    child: sideBarTabs,
    ),
```

And:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String username = 'user name';
  String userEmail = 'email address';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    getLanguage();
  }

  String language;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  Map data;

  String news;
  String signIn;
  List<Tab> tabs;
  ListView sideBarTabs;

  Future<void> getCurrentUser() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      if (_auth.currentUser() != null) {
        username = prefs.getString('username');
        userEmail = prefs.getString('useremail');
      } else{
        username = 'App name';
        userEmail = 'test@app.com';
      }
    });
  }

  Future getLanguage() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int lang = prefs.getInt('Language');

    setState(() {
      if (lang != 1) {
        language = 'ku';
        news = 'هه‌وا';
        signIn = 'بچۆ ژووره‌وه‌';
        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      } else{
        language = 'ar';
        news = 'أخبار';
        signIn = 'تسجيل الدخول';
        sideBarTabs = ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(username),
              accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                child: new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
                  );
                  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(news),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
                )),
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _SignInWithGoogle();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(signIn),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                )),
          ],
        );
      }
    });

  }

  Future<String> _SignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('username', user.displayName);
    prefs.setString('useremail', user.email);
    //prefs.setString('IdToken', await user.getIdToken());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 9,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: tabs,
      ),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        "App Name",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
    child: sideBarTabs,
    ),
```

I know my code is a a bit complicate because my tabs are dynamic and that's where the issue but I need it. Th issue is the username variable when the application runs it's whereas app name even if the user logged in or not, or in some of my codes above when user logged in shows the name or if the user not logged in already the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not readable, but if you need know if there is an user already logged or not and then build your UI element you should use FutureBuilder to accomplish this.

An snippet is:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasData){
          //then there is user logged, so you return your layout here..
          var user = snapshot.data; // this returns you logged firebase user

          return MyWidgetForLoggedUsers( user );
        }

        // so there is no user logged
        return Container(
          child: Text("There is no user active"),
        );

      },
    );
  }
```

Inside the builder you can use `snapshot.connectionState` for more refined control. Other option is use StreamBuilder with the same principles

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted but it still helped alot. thanks